# how to determine zero entries in a vector

Tags: linear-algebra

I am writing an optimization expression and in the constraints part, I want to limit the number of non-zero entries of the vector to a certain number R.

Suppose if the vector is M dimensional, then I would like to have R entries to be non-zero and (M-R) entries to be zero.  I want to have a vector expression or multiply of add or any function which I can write in the constraint part that ensure certain amount of non-zero entries or certain amount of zero entries.

I know how to limit the entries to certain number of 1s. If you equate the square of the norm of the vector to the value of R, you would limit the non-zero entries to R provided the vector only contains 0 and 1. However in case I have real numbers and zeros and I want to limit the number of non-zero entries, what could be the vector expression of function ?

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for the 0-norm, which is exactly the number of non-zero elements in a vector. So your constraint looks like

$$
\| x\|_0 \leq R
$$

However, the term norm here is used loosely, since the 0-norm is not really a norm (it does not satisfy triangle inequality). In fact, the constraint above is non-convex, and problems involving the minimization of 0-norm are NP-hard.

Still, under certain conditions, the 0-norm can be relaxed into 1-norm (which is much easier to deal with), without changing the solution to the optimization problem (see compressive sensing). Whether this applies to your case depends on the structure of your optimization problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. My optimization problem has M dimensional decision variables and the element values of the M dimensional vectors can go from 0 to less than 1 i.e 0≤x<1. Do you think I can use the relaxation in to 1-norm ?

Comment: Secondly, I am looking at ∥x∥_0 = R rather than the less than or equal to and for my optimization problem, this would come in the constraints rather than in the objective function.

Comment: What is your objective function?

Comment: Hi. I  have been a bit late but here is my optimization function. I am seeking help to find the best possible way to solve it. Any help would be wonderful.http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942333/how-to-solve-non-linear-optimization-problem-with-division

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit problematic to say that exactly $R$ should be non-zero, because then you have to define first what constitutes non-zero in your model (is $10^{-15}$ nonzero? If so, you will have massive problems to express this as it is essentially numerical noise to a numerical solver)

If you mean *at most* $R$ elements non-zero then it is easily described, when $0\leq x \leq 1$, as $x\leq \delta, \sum \delta \leq R$ where $\delta$ is a binary vector of length $M$.

BTW, strict inequalities are not possible in practice. You would have to write that as a strict inequality using a margin $0\leq x \leq 1-\epsilon$ where $\epsilon$ is a small constant, but large enough not to drown in the general numerical tolerances of the solver (somewhere around $10^-7$ typically)

Comment: Good points. But your formulation is an integer programming instance, which is NP-hard, as well.

Comment: There is no exact alternativ, you have to accept the computational complexity.

Comment: L1 is the best convex approximation

Comment: Agreed, the best bet seems L1 relaxation, whether you formulate as integer programming or L0 norm.

Comment: Huh? Either you perform an $L_1$-relaxation to model the cardinality constraint ($L_0$-norm) and hope for the best, or you do integer programming as above to model it exactly.

Comment: Except that in order to solve integer programming you need to do L1 relaxation as well, which is no longer exact.

Comment: OK my bad, it seems like there are algorithms that solve IP exactly.

Comment: I have shared my optimization problem here. Can you please help me guide to use which problem solving technique http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/942333/how-to-solve-non-linear-optimization-problem-with-division